# how to install latest possible iTunes without Yosemite upgrade?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, itunes, install

My Mac is running OS X Mavericks (1.9.5) and iTunes 11.1.

After I upgraded my iPhone to iOS 7 to iOS 8, I get a message saying that I need at least iTunes 11.2 to connect to this iPhone. However, when I click on the "upgrade" button, App Store only gives me the option of upgrading to Yosemite. I can't find a way to just install iTunes 11.2 or whatever version without upgrading to Yosemite.

Is there any place where I can download older iTunes versions?

thanks!

Comment: FYI. when I open Apple Store it shows iTunes 12.0.1 as available update, so the 11.2 has been replaced with newer version.

Comment: http://www.apple.com/fr/itunes/download/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the latest version from the Apple Support Downloads [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1614)

Answer (score -1):

If you click on the more button, you can pick and choose which thing to upgrade.